# What is easiest way to change the name of Project and related Class libraries in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have solution which is having 4 subproject. Name is like following.

```
1- IFest          //Main project having forms
2- IFest.Data.Entity      //class library for Entity
3- IFest.WorkFlow         //class library to manage Bridge
4- IFest.Data.Logic       //class library to manage Data
```

All contains resource which uses in class. I want to change the name from IFest to MyEventApp.

Can anybody suggest me what is the easiest way that change the name and related reference?

Comment: Quick and dirty: **Backup/commit**. Edit->Find and Replace->Replace in Files. Verify.  Restore from backup/throwaway changes if it didn't work how you expected.

Comment: I'm using resharper so i'm not sure if this is a resharperfunction or not. but i right click the project, and selct rename from the refactor menu and then all the names change.